# Google suggestion search for more than one word

Tags: javascript, jsfiddle, google-suggest

i'm working with google-suggestion and i'm trying to get all suggestion. I found and example here

```
<div class="ui-widget">
    <input id="search" />
</div>
```

javascript code

```
$(function () {
    $("#search").autocomplete({
        source: function (request, response) {
            $.ajax({
                url: "http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20json%20where%20url%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fsuggestqueries.google.com%2Fcomplete%2Fsearch%3Fclient%3Dfirefox%26q%3D" + encodeURIComponent(request.term) + "%22&format=json",
                dataType: "jsonp",
                success: function (data) {
                    response(data.query.results.json.json[1].json);
                }
            });
        },
        minLength: 2
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/qjy6H/

when i enter more then one word it do not work(don't show suggestions).
Thanks for help. there is another question on this theme. Can i save result to an array and transfer it to html page? and how can i do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to replace spaces in `request.term` by a `+` sign:

Here is the working JS code:

```
$(function () {
    $("#search").autocomplete({
        source: function (request, response) {
            var searchTerm = "auto+" + request.term.replace(" ", "+");
            $.ajax({
                url: "http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20json%20where%20url%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fsuggestqueries.google.com%2Fcomplete%2Fsearch%3Fclient%3Dfirefox%26q%3D"
+ encodeURIComponent(searchTerm) + "%22&format=json",
                dataType: "jsonp",
                success: function (data) {
                    response(data.query.results.json.json[1].json);
                }
            });
        },
        minLength: 2
    }); });
```

You can see it working on this codepen: http://codepen.io/adrenalinedj/pen/MyOZGj

Comment: Can I add a word to the beginning of the string? For example my search string is "audi", and want to paste "auto" to the begining of string. I want to get only name of cars.

Comment: hi, i'm sorry i'm bit late. Can i save this array of json result and send it to my html? And how can i do that? Thank you